# android notification not working for 2.3 gingerbread

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications, android-2.3-gingerbread

this code is working for above version of 2.3 (not working for 2.3)

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_logo)
     .setContentTitle("My Title")
     .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
     .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
     .setContentText("My text");

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` you're intending to send broadcast to all possible receivers.
The problem is in:

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

It will NOT be used to start an Activity. So you cannot set any of the Activity-related flags like FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.

Remove it and it should work on GB too.

You can only set Activity-related Intent flags in a PendingIntent, as long as you call getActivity() to get the PendingIntent.